# Robot Framework: validating text that's not UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, robotframework

I have a few tests in RF (using the Java port by Hi-Fi) with Selenium 3. The thing is, I need to validate some texts that contain non UTF-8 characters.

My usual test to validate text compares against a variable where I previously stored the text I expect to find. Something like this:

```
*** Variables ***
${SOME TEXT}    Some text I need to find in the web application I'm testing

*** Test Cases ***
Validate main paragraph text  
  Open Home Page
  Open Browser                           ${URL}  ${BROWSER}
  Element Text Should Be                 ${ELEMENT LOCATOR}  ${SOME TEXT}
```

Problem is, the expected text I'm given contains some cp-1252 characters (e.g.: the 0x92 character that looks like an apostrophe: ’), so if I just store that in my ${SOME TEXT} variable I'll get this error: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 84".

I can't have the text changed either, I need to work with it as it is.

Any clues on what would be the best approach? Thanks.

Comment: Are the .robot files themselves stored in the windows cp-1252 format. This is typically the issue I have when facing these kind of encoding mismatch issues. If they are,  most editors allow you to convert the encoding of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As A. Kootstra said, I just needed to change the encoding in my files. Since I'm working on Eclipse, I went to Window > Preferences > General > Workspace and changed “Text file encoding” to UTF-8. This way I'm now able to enter all the expected characters and my files are saved in the right encoding.